# Parameters of GestureDetectorCompat constructor

Tags: android, gesturedetector, this

> **Apologize :-** 
>   due to my mistake,  because last time i didn't asked this Question properly  and that's why most of the answers posted below are related to  **"this"** keyword and  that's the reason i got that much down votes. **So i updated this Question, because i don't want to misguide anyone.**

.

> **EDIT-1 :**
>
> **Question-1**  My question was that why we pass **"this"** (Object of current class or MainActivity) twice in the **GestureDetectorCompact()** Constructor
>
> ```
>  new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
> ```

Rest of the block of code is given below,

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {
  protected void onCreate(){
      private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetector;
      this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
      gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);

   }
}
```

> **EDIT-2 : for quite close answer** you can click at following link
>
> [EpicPandaForce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32004370/5013940) 
>   **'s answer** is very close to my question and it is helpful as well.

Comment: Where did you get this code? Seems very strange code.

Comment: `this` means the instance of the class that you are in.

Comment: it is MainActivity class from the from MainActivity.java file which is automatically created when we start new App in android Studio @KingofMasses

Answer (score 3):

The `this` keyword, which exists in many OOP languages, is a reference to the current instance of the object in which you are contained in memory..

Your example:

```
this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
```

You are basically saying:
This instance - access `gestureDetector` is equal to a new instance of `GestureDetectorCompat` that is constructed with 2 paramaters, in this case, both of them references to this instance of `MainActivity`.

As people are saying, this is a fundamental principal and it may be more beneficial for you to start with building a strong foundation in Java before moving on to Android.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. it helped me a lot. But i want  to ask two more thing, FIRST:-  where you are saying " This instance - access gestureDetector is equal to a new instance of GestureDetectorCompat" i want to know that is it equal or we are assigning a new object of "GestureDetectorCompat" to "this.gestureDetector".  and SECOND :- thing is that why we use two "this" here because both of them referencing to same class "MainActivity".. Please make me correct where i am wrong ......

Answer (score 1):

If you want to understand `this`, probably you should read  [*this*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

Android is a Java based platform and a good Java/OOP knowledge is required in order to make (native) apps.

I strongly suggest you to read at least one Java/OOP book/tutorial. Some good examples are:

- Bruce Eckel, Thinking in Java (a great classic)
- [Oracle Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/TOC.html)
- [Object Oriented Programming on Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Object_Oriented_Programming) (no specific language)

Good learning!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity 
    extends 
          ActionBarActivity 
    implements 
          GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, 
          GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

  private Context context;
  private GestureDetector.OnGestureListener onGestureListener;
  private GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener onDoubleTapListener;

  private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
      this.context = this; //mainActvity instance as a context
      this.onGestureListener = this; //mainActvity instance as GestureDetector.OnGestureListener
      this.onDoubleTapListener = this; //mainActvity instance as GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener

      //the gesture detector of this activity instance
      this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(context, onGestureListener);
                                            //activity as context
                                                  //activity as onGestureListener
      gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(onDoubleTapListener);
                                              //activity as double tap listener
   }
}
```

For more information, read about the constructor of `GestureDetectorCompat` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/GestureDetectorCompat.html#GestureDetectorCompat(android.content.Context,%20android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener))

Answer (score 0):

Here,

```
this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
```

the first "this" is referring the 'context' and second "this" is referring to the 'listener'.

You can have a look on this,

```
public GestureDetectorCompat(Context context, OnGestureListener listener)      {
    this(context, listener, null);
}
```

GestureDetectorCompat is the constructor in which we are passing the two "this" keywords, meaning first is context(which refers to the object of current class) and the second one is the listener.

Comment: No, both `this` words are references to the same object.  It just happens to be both a `Context` and an `OnGestureListener`, which is why it can be used for both parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Definition of GestureDetectorCompat constructor is,

> > GestureDetectorCompat(GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
> >     GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener) { }

So There is need of 2 arguments to call this function. In your case MainActivity is implementing both the Listener interfaces, that's why you need to pass the same reference in both the arguments to handle the callbacks respective to both the interfaces.

In some other implementation, both the interfaces can be handled separately too.

Answer (score -2):

`this`

Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using this.

Over here `this` refers to current Activity called `MainActivity`